# Problem with binding c# dropdown with sharepoint list items

Tags: development

I have a dropdown list in my visual web part in c# and i am trying to bind dropdown list from sharepoint list items.

And I have the following code:

```
SPList list = web.Lists["Authors"];  
drpbind.DataSource = list.Items;  
drpbind.DataValueField = "Id";   
drpbind.DataTextField = "FullName";   
drpbind.DataBind();
```

And when I run this an error is being thrown saying that the Column `FullName` does not exist in the list. I tried to assign with column guid but its not working.

Help me please!

Comment: are you sure that the FullName has already existed in your list? this code should be working!

Comment: Yes I am 100% sure that column `FullName` exist in my list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have provided the correct field name at `drpbind.DataTextField = "FullName";`

if it's not working Try to retrieve list items as `data table` as shown below

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList list = web.Lists["Authors"];
            drpbind.DataSource = list.Items.GetDataTable();
            drpbind.DataTextField = "FullName";
            drpbind.DataValueField = "ID";
            drpbind.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Check a complete example at [Bind a dropdown from SharePoint List via c#](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/11/01/bind-a-dropdown-from-sharepoint-list-c/)

Comment: list.Items.GetDataTable(); was the solution. Thanks Mohamed.